# Delete entire row across two tables (inner join?)

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete a row of data across two tables. I have the following code which isn't working:

```
DELETE
FROM PROCESS_OWNER.ARTIFACTS
JOIN PROCESS_OWNER.ARTIFACT_METADATA
ON ARTIFACTS.ARTIFACT_ID = ARTIFACT_METADATA.ARTIFACT_ID
WHERE ARTIFACT_LABEL = 'getTest'
```

I get the error message:

> "SQL command not properly ended"

Would really appreciate some help as I am struggling to get to grips with Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with a join. DELETE FROM has to target a single table. You could do this:

```
DELETE FROM PROCESS_OWNER.ARTIFACT_METADATA WHERE ARTIFACT_ID = (SELECT ARTIFACT_ID FROM PROCESS_OWNER.ARTIFACTS WHERE ARTIFACT_LABEL = 'getTest');
DELETE FROM PROCESS_OWNER.ARTIFACTS WHERE ARTIFACT_LABEL = 'getTest';
```

Comment: Thank you for the help - however, i found about about ON CASCADE DELETE and ended up using that instead so i can have one DELETE query

Comment: @Ryan - Yeah that works, but it's also pretty dangerous because it can delete stuff without you realizing it's doing it. Not something I'd ever use personally.